# No code workflow solution to copy document from library to another library in the site collection (but not same site)

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I am trying to build a very simple SPD workflow on a document library. All i need is that when a document is uploaded, a copy of this document is copied to another library in the site collection (not same subsite (web)).

The SPD action copy list item seems to only allow me to copy the item to a library in the same Web.
Is there a way to have the SPD copy the document to a library in the parent Web? I prefer a **no-code** workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint 2010 there is an out-of-the-box  *Content Organizer* which uses a Drop Off library and based on rules 'distributes' documents

[This 3 part blog](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-1-a-cool-new-feature-for-managing-your-content/) is a great starting point

[image]